# Combine Single Observable with Observable.from(array)

Tags: android, rx-java

Given the following input:

```
Observable<Class1> obs = {{super complex long method}}
List<Class2> inputList = {{simple list}}
```

I'd like to be able to create the following:

```
Observable<Class3> output
```

that emits the result of applying method `input.transform(Class1 c)` to each of the inputs in the inputList.

What I've come up with so far is a combination of zip & repeat:

```
Observable<Class3> output = Observable.zip(obs.repeat(), Observable.from(inputList), 
                            (class1, class2) -> class2.transform(class1));
```

However, the repeat is way too extreme, it emits multiple repeated items before the zip kicks in.

Another thing I tried was using `combineLatest`, but since my List emits first, I ended up with only the last item of the list being combined with the class1 instance.

What other combination of operators might make sense?

Comment: You can just change the parameter order, like `zip(Observable.from(inputList), obs.repeat(), ...)`.

Comment: @zsxwing Dude that actually worked! Is this also the most logical way to do this? And can you explain why this is working? If so, please make it an answer so I can accept it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just change the parameter order, like `zip(Observable.from(inputList), obs.repeat(), ...)`.

`zip` will subscribe the first `Observable` and then the second `Observable`. In your example, the first `Observable` is infinite (e.g., `obs.repeat()`), RxJava will request 128 items at first. That's why you saw `obs.repeat()` emitted a lot of items before subscribing the second `Observable`.

If changing the parameter order to `Observable.from(inputList), Observable.from(inputList)`, RxJava will subscribe `Observable.from(inputList)` at first, since it's a synchronous `Observable`, RxJava will consume it and know its length at once (assume its length is less than 128), then RxJava will request items from the second `obs.repeat()` using this length. So it won't require more than the necessary items.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like what you want to do is to take each input from `obs`, apply a set number of functions defined in a list to each of the items in `obs`, then flatten that output back into an Observable of type `Class3`.  In that case I think flatMap is a good choice, because it clearly signals the intent: that you are applying many functions per item of input, then flattening the stream.

Here's an example (pardon the Java6-ness of it):

```
Observable<Class3> output = obs.flatMap(new Func1<Class1, Observable<Class3>>() {
    @Override
    public Observable<Class3> call(final Class1 class1) {
        return Observable.from(inputList).map(new Func1<Class2, Class3>() {
            @Override
            public Class3 call(Class2 class2) {
                return class2.transform(class1);
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: This sounds like a nice solution. The only thing I'm afraid of is that the `map` method might not preserve order. It is very important in my scenario that the order is preserved.

Comment: Map does not affect the order of the stream, by definition (since it simply maps input 1-1). If you mean flatMap will not preserve order, that is true. In that case you can simply replace it with concatMap and order will be preserved.